# 2 file upload input fields in one form yii2

Tags: php, file-upload, upload, yii2

I have table with 2 columns (pic,pic2) my upload form works for the first file input. name of the picture records into column "pic" and file uploads to the server. How can i extend it to upload 2 files? Help pls

**model**

public $upload_file;

```
    public function uploadFile() {
    // get the uploaded file instance

    $image = UploadedFile::getInstance($this, 'upload_file');

    // if no image was uploaded abort the upload
    if (empty($image)) {
        return false;
    }
    $dir = Yii::getAlias('@frontend' . '/web/' . Yii::$app->params['fileUploadUrl']).$this->pic; 
    if (file_exists($dir)) {
        unlink($dir);
    } 
    // generate random name for the file
    $this->pic = time(). '.' . $image->extension;
    // the uploaded image instance
    return $image;
}

public function getUploadedFile() {
    // return a default image placeholder if your source avatar is not found
    $pic = isset($this->pic) ? $this->pic : 'default.png';
    $dir = Yii::getAlias('@frontend' . '/web/' . Yii::$app->params['fileUploadUrl']);
    if (!is_dir($dir)) {
        FileHelper::createDirectory($dir);
    } else {
        return $dir . $pic;            
    }

}
```

**action in controller**

```
    public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Blog();

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {

        $upload_file = $model->uploadFile();

        if ($model->validate()) {   
            if($model->save()) {

                if ($upload_file !== false) {
                    $path = $model->getUploadedFile();
                    $upload_file->saveAs($path);
                }

                return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
            }

        }
    }

    return $this->render('create', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);

}
```

**view**

```
    <?= $form->field($model, 'upload_file')->widget(FileInput::classname(), [
    'options' => ['accept' => 'image/*'],
]); ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'upload_file2')->widget(FileInput::classname(), [
    'options' => ['accept' => 'image/*'],
]); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found a solution this way :)

everything in controller

```
    public function actionRegistration()
{
    $model = new Registration();
    $i = 0;

    $imageArray = ['upload_file1','upload_file2','upload_file3','upload_file4'];
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {

        foreach ($imageArray as $imageUpload) {
            $i++;
            $field_name = 'pic'.$i;
            $image = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, $imageUpload);
            // if no image was uploaded abort the upload
            if (empty($image)) {
                return false;
            }

            // generate random name for the file
            $model->$field_name = 'pic'.$i.'_'. time(). '.' . $image->extension;

            if ($image !== false) {
                $pic = $model->$field_name ? $model->$field_name : 'default.png';
                $dir = Yii::getAlias('@frontend' . '/web/' . Yii::$app->params['fileUploadUrl']);
                if (!is_dir($dir)) {
                    FileHelper::createDirectory($dir);
                }

                $image->saveAs($dir.$pic);
            }

        }
        if (!$model->save()){
            var_dump($model->errors);
        } 
        return $this->refresh();
    }

    return $this->render('registration', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just write same code for `'upload_file2'`

```
$image2 = UploadedFile::getInstance($this, 'upload_file2');
...
```

or you can use some caind of widget for multiple upload files like [that](http://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/fileinput#basic-usage)

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need two seperate inputs for upload - you can do the following - add 'maxFiles' to rules of your model.

`public function rules()
    {
      return [
         [['upload_file'], 'file', 'skipOnEmpty' => false, 'extensions' => 'png, jpg', 'maxFiles' => 2],
        ];
    }`

and in uploadFile action change:

`$image = UploadedFile::getInstance($this, 'upload_file');`

to: 
`$image = UploadedFile::getInstances($this, 'upload_file');`

and lastly in your view change

`<?= $form->field($model, 'upload_file')->widget(FileInput::classname(), [
    'options' => ['accept' => 'image/*'],
]); ?>`

to:

`<?= $form->field($model, 'upload_file[]')->widget(FileInput::classname(), [
    'options' => ['accept' => 'image/*', 'multiple' => true] ,
]); ?>`

Comment: the problem is that i need 2 separate fileinputs :c

Comment: ahh in that case I would suggest using Kartiks FileInput widget

Comment: im using it:) use kartik\file\FileInput;